# visual studio directories and include paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

someone please help me with this issue, i do not think i understand this clearly:

in visual studio when i create a solution it asks me for a path where to create it

say for the directory where to create i say  c:\work\
 and i say "sol1"  for the name of the directory.

what i see is in c:\work\ a directory is created with name "sol1" 
 inside "sol1" there is another director "sol1" 
 and inside that i see folders like "Debug", "sol1", sol1.sln.

now say i have some preexisting code inside c:\work\codes\code1.cpp

i add code1.cpp to the visual sudio project "sol1" 
 adn then say i have something like #include "codes\code2.h" inside the first line of   code1.cpp

so now how should indicate the additional include directories ? if i say something like "../.." for additional include directories what is happening. what is my reference directory starting from which other directories should be visible.

It would be very kind of someone to clarify this issue. Please explain with a bit of detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use e.g.

```
#include "code2.h"
```

then the pre-processor (the program that handles the `#include` directive) *should* look for `code2.h` in the same directory as the source file where you have the `#include`.

So in your case, since you do this `#include` in `code1.cpp` and it seems like `code2.h` is in the same directory, you should `#include` like above.

Comment: but is it wrong to use something like #include "codes/code2.h" in the code1.cpp file ? code1.cpp and code2.h resides in the same directory.

Comment: @user1612986 If you use `"codes/code2.h"` then you must add the directory where `codes` is to the include search path and use e.g. `<codes/code2.h>` instead.